# Bypassing event.stopPropagation

Tags: javascript, event-handling, dom-events

I'm writing a JavaScript add-on (not in jQuery) which starts working when a certain event has been triggered. It works fine on most of the sites, but I encountered problems in sites that use `stopPropagation()`.
Is it possible to bypass this and attach the event anyway?

Comment: javascript add-on? do you mean firefox add-on?

Comment: It's JavaScript code that is activated when the site loads, pretty much like GreaseMonkey, except it's not Firefox specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How does `stopPropagation()` get in your way? (Add more description how/on what your add-on works/attaches).

The only thing `stopPropagation()` does, is to stop the event from bubbling up to the parent element of the element which received the event. Thus the event handlers on the parent aren't called. But multiple handlers for the same event directly on the element are all called.

So... as long as you bind your event-handler directly to the element which the event is first generated on first, you are ok. If you just try to listen for events on e.g. on `body` and rely on all events bubbling up to you, you are out of luck.

e.g. if you now click on the red div you will get an alert saying `sibling handler` and one saying `inline handler`although the earlier defined inline-`onclick` handler calls `stopPropagation()`.

(Note: this sample doesn't handle IE specifics which uses `attachEvent()` and `cancelBubble`)

```
<style type="text/css" media="screen">
    #parent1 { background-color: green; width:300px; height:300px }
    #test { background-color: red; width:200px; height:200px }
</style>

<div id="parent1">
    <div id="test" onclick="javascript:event.stopPropagation();alert('inline handler');"></div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    parent1.addEventListener('click',
        function(e) { alert('parent'); },
        false
    );
    test.addEventListener('click',
        function(e) { alert('sibling handler'); },
        false
    );
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks, I was actually looking for a more general way to catch all events and your comments about "out of luck" helped.

Answer (score 2):

For standards-compliant browsers, use the [capturing phase](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/events.html). For IE, you can capture mouse events by calling [setCapture](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536742(VS.85).aspx) on an element (probably the `body`). Once you've done your thing, call [fireEvent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536423(VS.85).aspx) on the `event` object's `srcElement`.

Comment: Thanks, but I need to capture all events, and not just on one object.

Comment: Capturing an event on the document will capture it no matter what element it is triggered on; IE will only allow mouse events to be captured. Can you describe why you want to capture _all_ events on an arbitrary page?

Comment: I admit that this is a valid idea. An actually I thought about it as I wrote my answer. But using the capturing phase will give you many headaches. Every browser supports the capturing phase a little different. `addEventListener(x,y,true)` behaves slightly different from browser to browser. Of course IE has his own way of doing things (`setCapture`, `relaseCapture`). And IE (at least <= IE6) only supports catching of mouse events in the capturing phase.

Comment: Andrew, thanks. I'm not sure I can reveal any more details at the moment.

jitter, thanks.

Comment: @jitter could you elaborate a bit on the "headaches" and differences between browsers? I'm working on a library [here](http://github.org/unphased/ply) that does a lot of managing events and I'm having a hard time finding articles that summarize these differences. I'd like to be able to get around `stopPropagation()` breaking functionality. I hope you could shed some light on this.